# Azure Databricks, how to auto download csv into local network drives?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

My job currently implemented Azure Databricks. Is it possible to have my dataframes be automatically downloaded as csv to a local network drive path on a recurring basis?

For example, our company have recurring reports and was hoping I could automate this by creating the dataframe in databricks and somehow have azure download the csv into a specific path in our company network folder.  Would this be possible?

FYI, I understand i could save the csv file to filestore (dbfs), but the main problem is..how can I or azure have the csv be AUTO-populated into our company network on a recurring basis?

Answer (score 2):

Write the file to blob storage, or a data lake rather than dbfs.

Use Azure Data Factory to run the notebook and then copy the output file to your in prem network.

You will need an integration runtime to be installed somewhere in your network for the file copy to access your network.

Comment: interesting, thank you.    Do you happen to know about virtual network peerings?  And how that can be worked on?  out of curiousity.